# Acumatica How to Write off supplier balances

Tags: acumatica

When it comes to customer invoice balances outstanding, you can write off the amount using balance write off feature under process - recurring - write off balances and credits. This can be done at the time of creating initial payment or later as a process.  However when it comes to AP invoices and supplier balances, no such feature exists?

thanks

Comment: No, there is not such feature. What is the meaning of writing off balance of the vendor? It is like deciding that you should not pay to the vendor your debts.

Comment: for example Supplier invoice from 2 years ago may have small amount outstanding and no credit from supplier or supplier is bankkrup

Comment: It happens fairly regularly that a supplier will have small differences. I cannot believe that this simple functionality is not built in.